# Посчитать количество вхождений слов

Tags: python, dict

## ЗАДАЧА.

> Строка на входе и которое возвращает слово, содержащее все уникальные слова в качестве ключей и количество вхождений в качестве значений

import string

```
text = 'A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.'

for c in string.punctuation:
    text = text.replace(c, ' ')

print(text)
```

Comment: Язык-то какой? Petooh? Кобол?

Comment: язык сдесь питоновский

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меня больше волнует, какой тут язык: "*Строка* на входе и *которое возвращает слово*, *содержащее все уникальные слова* в качестве ключей и количество вхождений в качестве значений import string"

Понять практически невозможно.  Строка, которая возвращает слово? Слово которое содержит все уникальные слова? 
Но если я правильно догадался, то вот примерно так:

```
from collections import Counter
text = 'A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.'
list_text = text.lower().replace('.', '').split()
counts = Counter(list_text)
print(counts)
```

Получаем:

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'journey': 1, 'of': 1, 'thousand': 1, 'miles': 1, 'begins': 1, 'with': 1, 'single': 1, 'step': 1})
```

Comment: Да, похоже на то что мне вроде надо. Спасибо! 
Подскажите где можно документацию на "from", "collections", "Counter" полистать?.

Comment: Вообще-то благодарности на этом сайте принято выражать несколько по другому. Если вам не ясно, что такое "from", то очень сильно подозреваю, что вы что-либо вообще по Python читали, ибо это объясняется в любой книжке на третьей странице.  Про ""collections", "Counter"  "полистать" можно например вот тут https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html

Comment: Ок, это дело поправимо.  Новачок!